# Ontology in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, taxonomy, ontology

Recently, I get some new topics to work on. The topic is **Ontology in SharePoint 2013**. I've googled few days and able to know that Ontology term is **used with Taxonomy** in SharePoint. It will improve and use in search functionality but **couldn't able to get the exact meaning, use and implementation of Ontology**.

So **my questions are**:

1. What is  the Ontology in terms of SharePoint 2013?
2. Where Ontology term is used in SharePoint 2013?
3. How to use Ontology in SharePoint 2013?
4. Is it possible to use in SharePoint Online or only with SharePoint on-premise?

I got the references:

- http://www.kmworld.com/Articles/Editorial/What-Is-.../Taxonomy-101-The-Basics-and-Getting-Started-with-Taxonomies-98787.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491121.aspx
- http://blog.wandinc.com/2013/03/common-taxonomy-questions-what-is.html
- https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/taxonomies-and-ontologies/
- https://blog.semantic-web.at/2014/07/15/from-taxonomies-over-ontologies-to-knowledge-graphs/

Please assist me, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

On my understanding, SharePoint Managed Metadata Service in all of his versions is able to approach only a taxonomy. That means to have a whole set of terms and create some relationships of parentship. You can also have the same term at different points in the tree belonging to several terms. That's, basically, what a taxonomy is.

Onthology refers to get the meaning of a word based on it's context. As an example, the word "party" has different meaning depending on the sentence. "I'm going to a party" and "I belong to a politic party" makes that the term "party" are in different parts of a taxonomy tree even with different children. So, in case you make a search, the onthology will extract that information from the context of your words and show you the proper results.

Going back to SharePoint, it needs an additional intelligent component able to extract that information from the context (include here the user  properties like job position, age, race, sex, etc, or the words involved in the question, etc)